# vb.net webbrowser regex extract to textbox

Tags: regex, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to extract from those numbers webbrowser

```
<tr style="font-size: 14pt;">
<td align="center">1</td>
<td align="center">2</td>
<td align="center">3</td>
<td align="center">4</td>
<td align="center">5</td>
</tr>
```

textbox.text = 12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using regex but it is not recommanded extract it like this:

```
Dim elemcol As HtmlElementCollection = Webbrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td")

For i As Integer = 0 To (elemcol.Count - 1)
    Textbox1.Text &= elemcol(i).InnerHTML ' here do whatever you want with its content
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks ElektroStudios for correction. I really have forgotton VB ;)

Comment: Just as a suggestion: Use an online code translator like the Telerik Code Converter, it will give you proper translation than the current (not working) one you have wrote. EDIT: No problem we are here to help us between!

Comment: I get the following errors
Type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection' has no constructors.
Type of 'I' cannot be inferred from an expression containing 'I'.

Comment: Try the new answer edit. I didn't tested, but that will no give the same error that you mentioned.

Comment: @Gaby_Gabor, I'm a c# programmer and haven't used vb for more than 8 years. thanks to ElektroStudios that corrected the syntax. now it should work

Comment: It works great
Thank you very much

but how do I extract only the numbers
It extracts and letters, how do you delete letters

Comment: now you should use regex for that: `Textbox1.Text &= Regex.Replace(elemcol(i).InnerHTML, "[A-za-z]","")`